# What to do if you can't change an object's class dynamically?

Tags: typescript, oop, inheritance

I am making a little soccer game in typescript and want to allow the user to control one player at a time but they can switch to control another player. I have a player class that contains properties and a getNextMove method that will be needed regardless of whether the player is controlled by the user or by the ai. However, I want the getNextMove method to implement different logic depending on whether the player is controlled by the user or the ai.

I am thinking to have a User class and an AI class that implement the Player class and subsequently the getNextMove method.

This is along the lines I was thinking

```js
interface Player {
    ...
    getNextMove()
}

class User implements Player{
    getNextMove(){
        // Take user input
    }
}

class AI implements Player{
    getNextMove(){
        // Decide next move automatically
    }
}
```

However, as the User changes players, the player they were just controlling will need to switch back to use the AI logic. I don't think the classes can be switch dynamically and I can't think outside of this Object structure or find something that could achieve what I want. Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Delegate to a strategy. Each Player has, let's say, an Engine, which can be an AIEngine or a UserEngine. When switching, change the engine of the player.

Comment: Think in the language you are actually writing in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the JB Nizet.

Use [strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) pattern.

```
class UserState {
    // properties
}

class User {
    constructor(){
        this.state = new UserState();
    }

    activateUserControl(){
        this.moveStrategy = new UserControlStrategy(this.state);
    }

    activateAI(){
        this.moveStrategy = new AIControlStrategy(this.state);
    }

    getNextMove(){
        this.moveStrategy.nextMove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Beautiful, this is a nice pattern!

Comment: I recommend you book "Head First Design Patterns". You can learn about many patterns and principles.